# get year from string '07-JUL-50'

Tags: python, datetime

I have a birth date field like:
    date = '07-JUL-50'

and when I wanna get the year I got this:

```
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y")
>>> my_date.year
2050
```

Is there an elegant way of get '1950'??

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation says that:

> When 2-digit years are accepted, they are converted according to the
>   POSIX or X/Open standard: values 69-99 are mapped to 1969-1999, and
>   values 0–68 are mapped to 2000–2068.

That's why you are seeing 2050.

If you want `1950` instead, it depends on what are allowed dates in your particular scenario. E.g. if date values can be only dates in the past, you can do something like this:

```
import datetime


def get_year(date):
    my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    if my_date > now:
        my_date = my_date.replace(year=my_date.year - 100)
    return my_date.year


print get_year('07-JUL-50')  # prints 1950
print get_year('07-JUL-13')  # prints 2013
print get_year('07-JUL-14')  # prints 1914
```

Hope that helps.